# Execute relevant tlb file during runtime (or build dynamically)

Tags: c#, typelib

I am writing an application in C# which enters data to  a third-party application using its tlb file. The third-party application is Rhapsody and the relevant files are: rhapsody.tlb, Interop.Rhapsody.com (the relevant third-party application in not important)
Every version of Rhapsody holds different version of rhapsody.tlb file.
My application should work with few versions of Rhapsody (7.4, 7.5.3, 7.6.1).
My code (the methods I call) can work with every version of Rhapsody without any change.
The problem is that I can build my code with only one tlb file. Therefore, the application can work properly only with one Rhapsody version.
I can let the user to enter his Rhapsody version on startup (or using xml file).
I can't use more than one exe file.

How can I execute the relevant tlb file during runtime (or build dinamically the file on runtime)?

Comment: Hmya, dealing with versioning is never a minor detail.  COM supports late binding, that will be a workaround.  In other words, do *not* use the .tlb and the interop assembly, use the *dynamic* keyword instead.  Making sure that you don't use a method or property that isn't available in an old version is however entirely up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I should write something like: dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(Rhapsody.Application));

Do I still need to add the tlb file as reference to my project? If yes, do I still need to write "using rhapsody"? Which version of tlb file should I add as reference (every rhapsody version has other tlb file)? If not, how does my application knows which Rhapsody version to bind and how it executes the relevant methods of the Rhapsody API?

Comment: Fairly sure I left no doubt: "do *not* use the .tlb and the interop assembly".  So of course you also no longer worry that you have multiple versions of them.

Comment: Hello, 
I have tried it. It didn't work.
My code is:
dynamic _app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Rhapsody.Application"));
_currentProject = _app.openProject("ProjectDestination");
Do you know what is missing?
Thank you

Comment: When I use Rhapsody 7.6.1 it is ok. But, when I use Rhapsody 7.5.3 _currentProject=NULL